# Server-side includes in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to generate Server side includes with express.js?

I'm trying to reuse my header and footer markup on different pages so I can make header/footer changes in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use partials.
You have to choose between some template engines. The default template engine is jade, so for this you have to do the following: create a file views/header.jade and put your stuff in. in your action you can render the partial with `partial('header');`

See the [expressjs docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#view-partials) for more.

Comment: Thanks Ben, partials is definitely what I was looking for

Comment: This has since changed, The templating engines can be found [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html).