# Node+Express equivalent of a server-side include?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side-includes

I am using NodeJS + Express.

I serve static pages using Express:

```
app.use( express.static( "/myStaticFolder/" ));
```

For some of the files in the static folder, I would like to dynamically include content.  I am looking for something quick and simple, like the equivalent of a server-side include.  Is there such a thing in the Node+Express environment?  Or are pages served from the Express static folder completely static.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507059/server-side-includes-in-expressjs

Comment: You cannot use partials, for Express 3.x. You have to use includes instead. Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014384/how-to-render-multiple-ejs-files-in-nested-form-in-node-js-and-express/17019406#17019406)

Comment: I'd recommend trying Jade for this. https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a11