# Make same <head> available to all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My web app routes amongst several html pages. Instead of uniquely defining the head for each file i.e. typing:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/interface.css"></link>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6873aa3c17.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    ...
  </head>
```

everytime, can I load all of these scripts programmatically across all the HTML files? (JQuery and Vanilla acceptable)

One method I tried was creating a `include.js` which would be a loaded script in each head with the following contents:

```
[
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js',
  'https://kit.fontawesome.com/6873aa3c17.js'
].forEach(function(src) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

(And probably a similar solution for links) but this did not work

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is absolutely possible, and good practice, but it should never be done in client side JS. Use a server side include in whatever language your server supports.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Do you know if Express has anything for this?

Comment: What is Express? Can't say I've ever used it - or even heard of it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That sort of surprises me: https://expressjs.com/

Comment: Ah ExpressJs, yeah I've heard of that :) See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10507059/519413) which Google turned up. I don't know much about ExpressJS/Node though, so I hope this is of some help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok good haha sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

If your website is a static HTML site without server-side logic, I'd recommend using `parcel` with `posthtml-include`

https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel

https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-include

https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/915#issuecomment-369489539

You will be able to include html files like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <include src="title.html"></include>
</body>
</html>
```